# Regex: Match a number of fixed length

Tags: python, regex

I need to match only those numbers that begin with 5 and are of exactly 4 digits in length.

This is my regex pattern:

```
m = re.findall(r'^5\d{3}', num)

Input: ["5560", "55110"]

Desired Output: 5560
```

What I'm getting: 5560, 5511

So, 5511 shouldn't be a part of the output as it is just a substring of 55110 and not a whole number in itself.

Comment: Use ends with anchor `$` at the end of regex. `m = re.findall(r'^5\d{3}$', num)`

Comment: woah thanks Tushar! That was quick!

Comment: If your input is like in your example, maybe a simple `int` comparison will do: `5000 <= int(item) < 6000`. Otherwise, use RegEx as pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following regex:

```
^\s*5\d{3}\s*$
```

Comment: If there is a space then it will be helpful

Comment: But what if he doesn't need to match string, starting with whitespace? Solution of given question should be strict. Then he can modify pattern, if he has additional conditions.

Comment: @MayurKoshti Not required here! see the input string, I dont' see any spaces there

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Input is a string  ...

```
num = '["5560", "55110"]'
m = re.findall(r'\D5\d{3}\D', num)
```